# Blender render.render() generated more files thant expected

Tags: python, blender

```
    bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
    tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
    links = tree.links
```

the above in blender script will generate additional files undefined in my script.
why?
for example I want to generate image in current workspece (D:/3d/)
but the blender also output different images in C: and unexpected dirs.

both remove nodes, and links wan't works.

Saved: C:\output\satellite_270.png\Image0003.png  # what I not expected
Saved: 'D:\3d\test\output\satellite_180.png' # what I wanted

del all nodes and links may solve the above problem

```
    for n in tree.nodes:
        tree.nodes.remove(n)

    for n in tree.links:
        tree.links.remove(n)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question, I don't know how to modified it. I am generate image, depth and normal from a camera in blender. My script works when only generate image. However, when I use the node_tree, and added normal output, it outputs more files in different dirs (not defined in my script). I also tried 'for n in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(n) [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42579/render-depth-map-to-image-with-python-script)' but also not works.

Comment: ``` 
    for n in tree.nodes:
        tree.nodes.remove(n)

    for n in tree.links:
        tree.links.remove(n) ```